# Arrival Time for Poisson Process with density

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution, density-function, poisson-process

[image]

Here is what I did to start this problem:

Let A be the first attack. Let $X_1, X_2, ... $ be the i.i.d. arrival sequence of attacks.
Then, $A = \sum_{i=1}^{k} X_i$ for each $k=1, ..., 5$. Let $Z_k$ be the time of the second attack. Then, $A = min_{1\leq k \leq 5}Z_k$ and $Z_k $ ~ $\Gamma (2, \frac{1}{5})$ with density $f(t) = \frac{te^{\frac{-t}{5}}}{5^2}$.

I don't know if this is the right way to approach this problem because it doesn't consider the random density function for the amount of time that the PC is powered on. I would appreciate any help either correcting my reasoning or showing me another way to approach the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of virus attacks are dependent on the time that the PC is on, thus the distribution of the virus attacks is

$$V|T\sim Po\left(\frac{t}{5}\right)$$

and thus

$$f_{VT}(v,t)=\frac{e^{-t/5}\left(\frac{t}{5}\right)^v}{v!}\cdot\frac{5}{4t^2}$$

The probability that $V=2$ is

$$\frac{1}{40}\int_1^5 e^{-t/5}dt=\frac{5e^{-1/5}-5e^{-1}}{40}\approx 5.64\%$$

---

The correctness of the solution can be verified with a calculator that gives

$\mathbb{P}[V=0]\approx68.06\%$

$\mathbb{P}[V=1]\approx 25.08\%$

$\mathbb{P}[V=2]\approx 5.64\%$

$\mathbb{P}[V=3]\approx 1.03\%$

$\mathbb{P}[V=4]\approx 0.16\%$

that is approx p=1.

---